# Opening External URL in JQuery UI Dialog on Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I have a custom template page I'm building for a wordpress site (using a modified Twenty Eleven theme).  In the page there are links that are created programmaticly. There will be several links such as this:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com.com/info.php?id=123" class="uimodal">More Information</a>
```

I would like any URL with the class of uimodal to come up in a jQuery UI modal window (dialog) but I'm having problems getting it to do so.

I've successfully loaded jQuery UI.  I have tried several code snippets online, not getting any errors via Firebug, it just doesn't load modal (just replaces the current page).

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hSRdr/

```
$(function() { // same as $(document.ready(function() {
    $('a.uimodal').on('click', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('<div>').append('<iframe src="' + href + '"></iframe>').dialog();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: This must be a WP problem, because your fiddle is obviously working but it wont work when I take it into WP

Comment: Is it wrapped inside `$(document).ready()`? I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Yes but I think its a wordpress problem.  I know with wordpress you can't use $(document) you must use jQuery(document) so I think its just something there.  I know your answer works so I've marked it as such.  Thanks!