# jQuery Function to load content from page into Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have the following function that should load the div id "content" into the Modal Dialog for any link with the id of "#modal".

EDIT

I understand that ID's must be unique, but in this instance, there is no repetition of #modal on any of the pages that would actually use this function. I have even made #modal a class by specifing .modal instead of #modal. the result is the same

END EDIT

```
// Load external content in modal
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#modal').on('click', function(event){
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                overflow: scroll,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: $link.attr('width')
            });

        $link.click(function(){
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

What happens though is that the click event just goes to the link instead of loading the external page into the Modal Dialog. All required jQuery and jQuery UI libraries are included and linked from the Google jQuery repository. From what I've read and examples I've seen this SHOULD work.

I have also tried using

```
$('#modal').bind('click', function(){
```

and

```
$('#modal').click(function(){
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ID-s should be **unique**! So no *"any link with the id of #modal"* - make it a class

Comment: I understand that, but in this instance, there is no repetition of #modal on any of the pages that would actually use this function.

Comment: use classes if you need to duplicate div names, classes can be duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes to the link because you didn't prevent the default anchor behavior.  use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#modal').on('click', function(event){ // <-- modal is a link with a `href`
        event.preventDefault(); // <--
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
```

An anchor with an href property - when clicked - goes to the link provided inside the href.  If you don't prevent that default action, it will go there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what's up with the `click` event you're wiring up at the bottom.  Sounds like `#modal` is an `a` element, though.  The link's default behavior is most likely the culprit here, so add `event.preventDefault();`.  I have added it to the first line of your `.on`.

Now, I'm not sure what that second click event is going to do, since you're wiring it up to the `#modal` link.

```
// Load external content in modal
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#modal').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: false,
                overflow: scroll,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: $link.attr('width')
            });

        $link.click(function(){
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

After the modal html is loaded, do you want it to open, or are you really waiting for the user to click `#modal` again to open the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#modal').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

If this fails try see this:

[Opening External URL in JQuery UI Dialog on Wordpress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695797/opening-external-url-in-jquery-ui-dialog-on-wordpress-page)